# Show directly that $\left\|\Pi^{n}(x,\cdot)-\pi\right\|_{TV} \longrightarrow 0$ where $\Pi$ is transition matrix of a Markov chain.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, ergodic-theory

Let $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Markov Chain such that $X_{n}$ is the maximum score obtained after $n$ throws of a fair dice. Therefore, the state set is $M=\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$.

I know that if we consider  the random variable  $Y_{k}$ which are the result of $k$th throw of our fair dice, then $(Y_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is iid with uniform distribution over $\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$, so, we have $X_{n}=\max\left\{Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n}\right\}$. Furthermore, the cumulative distribution of $X_{n}$ is
$$F_{X_{n}}(k)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \mathrm{if}\: k<1 \\
\frac{i^{n}}{{6}^{n}} & \mathrm{if}\: i\leq k <i+1 \:\: \mathrm{for}\: i=1,2,3,4,5.\\
1 & \mathrm{if}\:\: k\geq 6
\end{array}\right. $$
For other hand, the transition matrix is 
$$\Pi=\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6} \\
0 & \frac{2}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6} \\
0 & 0  & \frac{3}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6} \\
0 & 0  & 0  & \frac{4}{6}  & \frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{6} \\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & \frac{5}{6}  & \frac{1}{6} \\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right].$$
**My first objective is to find the invariant distribution with respect to our Markov chain**, we recall

> **Definition:** $\pi$ is an *invariant measure* if $\pi \Pi=\pi$. If in addition $\sum_{i\in M}\pi(i)=1$, then we say it is an *invariant distribution*

Find $\pi$ was easy, this comes from the uniform distribution, ie, $\pi(i)=\frac{1}{6}$ for all $ i \in M $.

**My question:** I need to show directly that
$$\left\|\Pi^{n}(x,\cdot)-\pi\right\|_{TV} \overset{n\rightarrow\infty }{\longrightarrow} 0\tag{*}$$
for all $x\in M$, where $TV$ means *total variation distance*.

**My attempt:** By this [link](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=6Cg5Nq5sSv4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA48&redir_esc=y&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false) (page 48) we have
$$\left\|\Pi^{n}(x,\cdot)-\pi\right\|_{TV} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{6}\left|\Pi^{n}(x,i)-\pi(i)\right|.$$
For other hand, we have that
$$\Pi^{n}=\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n} & \left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{n}  & \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{n}  & \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{n}  & \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n}  & 1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n} \\
0 & \left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{n}  & \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{n}  & \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{n} & \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n} & 1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n} \\
0 & 0  & \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{n}  & \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^{n} & \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n} & 1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n} \\
0 & 0  & 0  & \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n}  & \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{n} & 1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}  & 1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right].$$
In this sense, for example,  for $x=6$ we have 
$$\left\|\Pi^{n}(6,\cdot)-\pi\right\|_{TV} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right).$$
But this last one contradicts (*), which can not happen since it contradicts the Ergodic Theorem for Markov Chains  (see [Page 6 Theorem 1.3](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=hR7GCgAAQBAJ&pg=PP1&lpg=PP1&dq=Kulik%20Introduction%20to%20ergodic&source=bl&ots=xYQ8PnXo9q&sig=ExWmCMHxd_-h_dxQlvNvFi1ZNe0&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji8Z3P3srSAhUQ2mMKHb54CcYQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=Kulik%20Introduction%20to%20ergodic&f=false)).

***What is the mistake I am making? Or am I misinterpreting some of the concepts?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chain is absorbing at $i=6$ therefore $\pi(i)\neq 1/6$. Invariant distribution is $(0,0,0,0,0,1)$. Manual solution of $\pi \Pi=\pi$ give this answer immediately.